# как убрать кружок у radio button

Tags: android

есть такой код:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.inventor.views.togglebuttons.MyToggleButton
        my:typeface="@string/typefaceMuseo700"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_selector_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/pages_10"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/main_selector_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_alltext_size"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textOff="@string/activity_main_pages_10"
        android:textOn="@string/activity_main_pages_10"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/rec"
        android:textColor="@drawable/main_selected_text_color"
        />

    <com.inventor.views.togglebuttons.MyToggleButton
        my:typeface="@string/typefaceMuseo700"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/main_selector_width"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20 страниц"
        android:id="@+id/pages_20"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/main_selector_margin"
        android:textSize="@dimen/main_alltext_size"
        android:background="@drawable/rec"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textOff="@string/activity_main_pages_20"
        android:textOn="@string/activity_main_pages_20"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textColor="@drawable/main_selected_text_color"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

при нажатии на кнопку с использованием селекторов реализовано изменение цвета текста в кнопке и через background при нажатии же ставиться рамочка.
мне нужно реализовать такие кнопки с помощью radiobutton (нужно при нажатии на одну кнопку остальные ставились onChecked:"false" и так же менялся цвет текста и рамка вставала. но при создании radiobutton я столкнулся с проблемой: родной кружочек не убирается и если поставить:

```
android:button="@color/transparent"
```

то он все равно занимает место а нужно чтобы не занимал место.

как это реализовать?

Comment: Зачем вам радиобаттон в котором нет радиобаттона, а есть только текст?

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: тег [android studio] ставится для вопросов, которые связаны с проблемами в работе самой этой IDE, а не для демонстрации ваших предпочтений в выборе средства разработки. Ваш вопрос никак не связан с прблемами в данной IDE и этот тег здесь неуместен.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

если использовать `android:background` наряду с `android:button=transparent` то проблема решается